# Parsing Financial information from HTML

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, html-agility-pack

First attempt at learning to work with HTML in Visual Studio and C#. I am using [html agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) library. to do the parsing.

From this [page](http://www.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ:TXN&fstype=ii)  I am attempting to pull out the numbers from the "Net Income" row for each quarter.

here is my current progress, (But I am uncertain of how to proceed further):

```
        String url = "http://www.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ:TXN&fstype=ii"
        var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
        var document = webGet.Load(url);
        var body = document.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                            .Where(n => n.Name == "body")
                            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (body != null)
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all there's no need to get the body first, you can directly query the document for what you want. As for finding the value you're looking for, this is how you could do it:

```
HtmlNode tdNode = document.DocumentNode.DescendantNodes()
  .FirstOrDefault(n => n.Name == "td"
    && n.InnerText.Trim() == "Net Income");
if (tdNode != null)
{
  HtmlNode trNode = tdNode.ParentNode;
  foreach (HtmlNode node in trNode.DescendantNodes().Where(n => n.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Element))
  {
    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText.Trim());
    //Output:
    //Net Income
    //265.00
    //298.00
    //601.00
    //672.00
    //666.00
  }
}
```

Also note the `Trim` calls because there are newlines in the innertext of some elements.

Comment: how do I get that same result without the "Net Income" String printout. and also if you could check out the rest of the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959219/scraping-html-from-financial-statements